# what's the solution to the following Kepler-like problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, dirac-delta

**CONTEXT**

I'm working with a problem tangentially like the Kepler problem [1].

I'm trying to make sense of eccentricities $e$, where $e = -1$.  There are some thoughts about such eccentricities [2]. For example, from what I gather from [2] the trajectories are scattered orbits resulting from repulsive central potentials.

Nonetheless, I'd like to work out the following boundary value problem. Starting with the solution of the Kepler problem in [1], I eventually arrive at
$$ 
\frac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2} + u = -\frac{m}{L^2}  \frac{d}{du} V\left(\frac 1 u\right).
$$

I'd like to consider an infinite radial step function. By $R$, I denote a positive real  number.
$H(r-R)$, I denote a radial Heaviside step function  I write as
$$H(r-R) = \begin{cases} 0,& \textrm{for}~r < R;~\textrm{and}
\\
1,& \textrm{for}~r \geq  R.
\end{cases}$$
So, I write
$$V({\bf{r}}) = \lim _{k\rightarrow \infty} k H(r-R). $$ Further
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dV({\bf{r}})}{dr} 
&= \lim _{k\rightarrow \infty} k \dfrac{dH(r-R)}{dr} 
\\
&= \lim _{k\rightarrow \infty} k \delta(r-R). 
\end{align}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

I now substitute $l$ in place of $\frac{mk}{L^2} $so collecting all the constants
$$ 
\frac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2} + u = \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} \,l\,\delta\left(\frac{1}{u} - R\right).
$$

It seems to me that, owing to the nature of the Dirac delta function, I can arrive at the following differential equation.
$$ 
\frac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2} + u =  \delta\left(\frac{1}{u} - R\right).
$$

**MY SOLUTION**

I'm not in a position to go any further at this moment. I reckon I would do something similar to [3], which is to take the Laplace transform, use partial-fraction expansion, and then take the inverse Laplace transform.

I don't trust my own work herein in the slightest.

**QUESTIONS**

What is the equation of motion for the radius $r$  of a particle of mass $m$ in  a radial Heaviside (infinite) potential?

Constructive comments are welcome as are meaningful discussion.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem

[2] http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/reinsch/phys105spr2014/lectures/Lecture10_Charman__notes_two_body_16.pdf,  Holland, Peter R, "The quantum theory of motion : an account of the de Broglie-Bohm causal interpretation of quantum mechanics," Cambridge University Press, 1993.

[3] http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DiracDeltaFunction.aspx

Comment: [2]’s link was “not found on this server”

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. Link [2] is broken. As an alternative, try  Holland, Peter R, "The quantum theory of motion : an account of the de Broglie-Bohm causal interpretation of quantum mechanics," Cambridge University Press, 1993.